# Не получается загрузить скрипт c типом "module"

Tags: javascript, модули, cors

В файле `script.js` есть фичи `ЕS6` вроде `import`. По этому подключаю `script.js` как модуль, по скольку вычитал и на собственном опыте проверил, что без `type='module'` браузер выдаёт ошибку.
Но когда подключаю скрипт

```
<script type="module" src="script.js "></script>
```

Как модуль, в браузере `Chrome (v67)`, в консоли выскакивает ошибка:

> **Access to Script** at 'file:///D:/PROJECT/playing_field/src/script.js'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response.
>   Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Как её побороть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access to Script at 'file:///D:/PROJECT/playing_field/src/script.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> > Как её побороть?

`Dev` - это всё для среды разработки, прод или стадж там другие тулзы.

Поднять сервер, типа:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

или

Python2.6

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Python3.6

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

или

---

**Nodejs:**

```
http-server -p8080 -a localhost
```

Установка последнего производиться командой:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

---

Если вы нахдитесь в `nodejs` проекте, то возможные варианты:

- nodemon
- supervisor